# Convert retrained data into .pb format for ios camera example?

Tags: ios, tensorflow

I retrained image data using the tutorial at ((https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html)) I did all the steps until

> bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain

. I was wondering how to turn this image training data into a .pb file that I can use in the ios camera example.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a two step process.

1. Export model definition and weights:

   a. The graphdef (*.pb) using tf.train.write_graph: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/cc/index.html

   b. The weights (*.ckpt) using tf.train.Saver: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver
2. Merge the two components above into one protobuf (final *.pb) using the following script: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py

Comment: I am trying to create the tensorflow .pb graph file using terminal. Does this method also work for terminal?

Comment: You mean the Linux command line? Sure, there's nothing here that requires GUI.

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work now. I was wondering how to implement the .pb graph into the example, too. Do you just reference it, and then replace the .pb and label files in the .mm file?